# How do I make an application that shows a new random number every time you press enter in C#?

Tags: c#

So I want to make an application in Windows Forms Applications or something with C#, that shows a new random number every time I press enter, but I have no idea how I would do this.

In a console window I do it like this:

```
Boolean keepGoing = true;
do
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 101);
    Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
}
while (keepGoing == true);
```

But I need to do it in an application where I can style font size and stuff.

I would really appreciate if you guys could help me out!

Comment: Read about WPF and Windows Forms if you want to customization.

Answer (score 3):

Before anything else, you want to declare `Random rand = new Random()` outside of your loop, otherwise each number generated will be the same.

For full support with keyboards etc, you'd be better off making a simple WPF application and using this code to detect if `enter` has been pressed:

```
private void input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{                        
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)   
    {  
        // Run random number generator again 
    }             
}
```

Instead of recursively running a method, you would simply listen for a particular keyDown event (above) and, upon the correct key being used (in this case `enter`), you would call `NewRandomNumber()` again.

Comment: Could you walk me through the steps just after creating the WPF application in Visual Studio? That's as far as my knowledge of WPF goes. Do I need to create a box or something that will output my random number, and then that box will auto generate the method you're talking about? You shouldn't be able to write in the box, it should only output the number. I also don't know how to output something in WPF.

Comment: You could tie the event to a button press, or have a textbox that's listening for keydown events. There are hundreds of WPF tutorials out there, if you have a coding question feel free to post another question to seek advice. Comment sections are usually reserved for discussing an answer or providing a more indepth explantion.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Form Properties and set KeyPreview = true. Declare a new Random instance

```
Random rdm = new Random();
```

Then handle the KeyDown Handler like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {

            int number = rdm.Next(0, 101);
            label1.Text = number.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you declare `rdm` here, each number will be the same. You need to declare an instance of `Random` once, rather than each time you need a new number.

Comment: worked for me.. but I wrote that in like 2 minutes but I edited my answer.

Comment: Nearly all of my issues with using `Random` come from declaring it inside of a loop, perhaps it's different inside of a conditional statement? Either way, declaring it every time is unnecessary anyway :)

Comment: Technically there is no loop. There is an event and if you use it over and over in short succession it might behave like a loop. According to MSDN the issue is related to the fact, that the Random-Seed is dependant on the System.Time and that you require at least 15 milliseconds of time passed before you can create a new Seed which will produce a new random number.

Answer (score 0):

Yo should take out the creation of the random number, try this:

```
Boolean keepGoing = true;
Random rand = new Random();
do
{
    int randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 101);
    Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
}
while (keepGoing == true);
```